# If string contains word from list, return value adjacent to list value

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a set of cells, and each has, among useless information, a unique identifier. I also have a list of these unique identifiers, as well as what value each identifier corresponds to.

What I would like to do is find which, if any, identifier a cell contains, and then output the corresponding value, below is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97aKI.png

So where the cell contains "ADC", I would like excel to find where ADC comes up in the reference array, and then return the corresponding value.

If this can be done with a formula or a macro, either would be great. I have tried fiddling with index, match, and search, in various combinations, but nothing seems to be working. I have found creating a massive if statement to be impractical as there are about 70 unique values to search for.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

edit: I was recommended to use vlookup, but I am not looking for an identical match, but instead for a specific value contained within a string. If vlookup does have this functionality then could somebody show me how to put this into practice with my specific example?

Comment: see [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Also available in [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb).

Comment: As jeeped mentioned: vlookup will do... regarding the question try `"*ADC*"` as search string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method of a 'reverse-wildcard' lookup can be achieved is with the newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). This function can produce cyclic calculation and has an option (e.g. **6**) to discard errors. Use this to produce a row number on the match to the cross-reference table with the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) returning the actual value.

[image: Reverse VLOOKUP]

The formula in B3 is,

```
=INDEX(F$3:F$5, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$3)*SIGN(MATCH("*"&E$3:E$5&"*", A3, 0)), 1))
```

Note that `ROW(1:3)` is the *position within* F3:F5, not the actual row number on the worksheet. I've also scrambled the *Find* and *Insert* values in your original cross-reference table to avoid the perception of an associative lookup match.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Hi @Jeeped Thanks for the answer to this. It was really helpful. Just out of interest, if you wanted to know if there was more than one string matched and which strings they are? Currently it returns the string with the lowest index that is matched, but I can't for the life of me figure out what changes need to be made.

Comment: For the second, third, etc matches you need to adjust the *k* parameter of AGGREGATE's SMALL sub-function. Change the **1** at the right end to `COLUMN(A:A)` then fill right. Additionally, you will need to 'lock' column references like F:F into $F:$F so they do not shift and maybe wrap the whole thing in an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to avoid error messages in cases where there are no second or third matches.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. For cell with text more than 255 characters, it is needed to split the text before using this formula.