# Excel - How to find a specific name within a cell then return that name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The image should clarify what I'm trying to figure out. I need a formula to get the outputs in column D that lets me search for the values in column B within column A and return the values in column B.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Close duplicate of [If string contains word from list, return value adjacent to list value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628660/if-string-contains-word-from-list-return-value-adjacent-to-list-value/33629724#33629724).

Comment: @Jeeped Feel free to close.  It was easier to do than find a duplicate.

Comment: @ScottCraner - No worries; I couldn't immediately find an exact duplicate although I know I've produced several answer to 'flavours' of this problem. The one that cropped up is close but actually returns an adjacent column not the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$5,B2)),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving Edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: select the top cell only.  Put the formula in.  Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm, then fill down as normal.