# excel aggregate match return multiple values

Tags: excel, match, aggregate

I have been working on an excel project where I have a list of items with a description field that I am searching and on the second sheet a list of words to search for with associated numbers. If I match on one of the words in the description it returns the number from the second list. I actually found the answer on this on another post ([If string contains word from list, return value adjacent to list value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628660/if-string-contains-word-from-list-return-value-adjacent-to-list-value?answertab=active#tab-top)) but I am unable to figure out how to handle multiple matches. If possible I want to return all possible matches. I am too new to comment on that question in particular so I couldn't piggyback. any help?

Comment: http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/

Comment: @WNG. appreciate the quick response. maybe I can help with my question a little. here is the formula I have that is working.

=INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$5002,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(1:5000)*SIGN(MATCH("*"&Sheet1!A$2:A$5002&"*",C2,0)), 1))

C2 contains the item name with very limited information. Using that I can get some of my items to match. I want to use another column that contains the entire detailed description (which causes multiple matches). If I change C2 to F2 i get #NUM error. 

On the other question, there was an answer on how to do that that I couldnt get to work. (changing k value)

Comment: Do you want the output in the same cell, different cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner preferable consecutive cells in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `1` at the end to `COLUMN(A:A)`

And make sure all other references are absolute:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5002,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5001)*SIGN(MATCH("*"&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50002&"*",$C2,0)), COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

Put the formula in the first cell and copy over enough column to get all returns and down the rest of the data set.

Comment: I did that but return zero matches when I know for certain there should be 2 matches on my first one and one match on my second one.

Should COLUMN(A:A) be literal or should I be referencing the columns I want the results in?

Comment: it is literal.  it is a counter and not an actual reference.

Comment: Then I am missing something. I am returning zero results. when I use the original formula I can match on the name only column and return a number, but if multiple matches I only get one result. If I use the updated formula, I return nothing regardless of which column I search (name only or full description)

Comment: @BrentTobiczyk sorry missed the `*` when I copied your formula.  see edit.

Comment: unfortunately still no go.

The only thing I changed was C2 to reference the detailed description column. copy/paste/fill. all blank

Comment: basically I have the following columns
Sheet 1 -
M - Contains the detailed description
Sheet 2 - 
A - Category Names
B - Category Number

I want to search M2 for any of the names from A. For each match I want to return the associated number from B and display each match in AA, AB, AC etc. The original formula worked but would only return one results regardless of matches. Unfortunately my excel-fu is not the best.

Comment: @BrentTobiczyk - when I copied Scott's formula MATCH didn't work - I just deleted MATCH in formula and retyped and all was OK, probably an issue with copying from here....

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on the more common INDEX/MATCH formula. By wrapping SMALL around an AGGREGATE array, you can identify each of the matches in the index.

NOTE: It's an array formula so you'll need to hit ctrl + shift + enter, then just copy the formula down for the number of matches you want to display. (If you're getting the #NUM error, it could mean you forgot to hit ctrl + shift + enter)

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$5002,SMALL(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$5002) - ROW($A$2)+1 / ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*SEARCH_TEXT_GOES_HERE*",$A$2:$A$5002))),ROW($2:2)),ROWS($2:2)))}
```

This formula is based off of the formula and explanation [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-all-partial-matches).